# Doubt regarding shortest distance between exponential and logarithmic curve?

Tags: calculus, geometry, tangent-line

Consider the two functions functions : $e^x$ and $\ln x$.

[image]

I know that the shortest distance is along the common normal. But my teacher said that "both the curves are inverse of each other and symmetrical about the line $y=x$. Hence , the common normal must be perpendicular to the line $y=x$."

My problem is only regarding the last line. My teacher said it in a way that it seems obvious. But I cannot prove that why the normal must be perpendicular to the line $y=x$ also. I'm especially looking for a geometric proof.

Comment: This page might be of interest: [Shortest distance between two non-intersecting differentiable curves is along their common normal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2882830/shortest-distance-between-two-non-intersecting-differentiable-curves-is-along-th)

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth Thanks sir. But I have already read that post and know that fact. My question is instead that why it shall be normal to the line $y=x$ as well in addition to being normal to both curves.

Comment: Perhaps you may check [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1500352/minimum-distance-between-ex-and-ln-x).

Comment: @AntonVrdoljak That was helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Symmetry about the line $y=x$ means that reflection across that line carries one graph to the other. Since reflection preserves distance, the reflection of the line joining the two closest points must likewise be a line joining two (other?) closest points. Since it's "geometrically clear" that there can be only one such pair of points, the reflection of the line must be itself. That means that the line is perpendicular to the "mirror" $y=x$. (For example, reflection across the line sends a line with slope $m$ to a line with slope $1/m$. So, if $m=1/m$, we must have $m=1$ or $m=-1$. But our line joins two points on opposite sides of $y=x$ and thus cannot be parallel to $y=x$.)

Comment: Thanks sir. My main problem was to rigourously prove that perpendicular to mirror due to distance preservation argument.